# Rear derailleur adjustment

Tags: shimano, repair, derailleur-rear, shifting, adjustment

I have a 7 speed Shimano derailleur. It shifts really good from 1 to 6 but when
I try to shift from 6 to 7 it just doesn't want to shift. Can someone help me?

Comment: You may have to tweak the hi/lo adjustment screw, depending on whether by 7 you mean the largest or the smallest cog. Do so with care with steps of less than a quarter turn to avoid throwing the chain off or into the spokes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My bike shifting won’t surpass 6](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/67183/my-bike-shifting-won-t-surpass-6)

Comment: This is the question I should have asked but did not. Thanks. The suggested duplicate does not do it for me, that seems to be about a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here seems quite obvious, you have to tweak the H screw on the back of the derailleur. You have to unscrew it just until you are able to shift down to the last gear. Don't unscrew too much, because the chain will escape out the last gear, since the shifter rely on that stop screw.

[image: Limits stop derailleur]